# Leaderboard rankings / mass data organization in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, organization, leaderboard

I am creating a new website that will be a 'leaderboard' for a game. Each user will have columns in the database for a statistic (e.g. kills, deaths, points, etc).

I need to sort this data and give each user a global ranking for their statistic, which would be another column in the table.

I have no idea where to start with this - how would I organize the tables in an efficient manner?

Answer (score 1):

You could put each statistic in a table with userid (or whatever the unique id for a user is) as the primary key.  But I wouldn't store the global ranking as a column.  I would calculate it in the application.

Comment: I need the global ranking throughout multiple pages. There will be leaderboards, but I need the user's global rank to be displayed in the profile page as well